# ESLint: Environment-specific rules

Tags: javascript, eslint, development-environment

At my company, we are trying to get our ESLint rules nailed down, and some of us have preferences that others do not share. What I'm wondering is if there's a way to have our company rules while still allowing individual developers to apply their own rules in their own local development environments, and then have the code they commit revert back to the company rules so that what's on the remote version control system uses the company rules.

I've tried Googling it, but all I've found are how-to's on how to create custom ESLint rules. This makes me believe it probably isn't possible, but I just wanted to shoot this out there in case anyone has come across a way to accomplish what I'm looking for.

EDIT
We're using git hosted on GitHub. We each use different IDEs, such as PHPStorm, VS Code, vim, etc.

Comment: I'm personally not aware of anything that would automatically do this for you.  Within my group we have npm scripts that perform the lint checks and prettier that the developers are expected to run prior to committing the code to the repo, and the lint check are also ran in the automated pipelines.  But yeah, not sure of anything automated.

Comment: @Taplar Yeah we may have to opt for something like that.

Comment: The duplicate question covers Java, but the principles are the same. You just need to use eslint as the filter.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for that resource, I'll definitely look into that.